# Finding a DTFT of a signal

Tags: dsp, fourier

I'm trying to figure out what's the DTFT of \$ (-1)^nx[n]\$. (I'm given the DTFT of \$x[n]\$)

So I tried this, but I can't figure out how to proceed from here, if this is even correct.
Any help and advice would be appreciated!

\$F_{DTFT}\{ (-1)^n x[n] \} = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n x[n] e^{-i\theta n}\$

\$=\sum\limits_{even \space n's}x[n]e^{-i\theta n}-\sum\limits_{odd \space n's}x[n]e^{-i\theta n} =\$

\$=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x[2k]e^{-i\theta 2k}-\sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}x[2m+1]e^{-i\theta (2m+1)} = ?\$

Thanks!

Comment: You could try using the property that relates multiplying signals in the time domain with convolving spectra in the frequency domain.

Comment: Thanks The Photon, I'll add my attempt at this as an answer, maybe you could look at it? (It's too long for a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that \$(-1)^n=e^{i\pi n}\$, so you get

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n](-1)^ne^{-in\theta}=
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n]e^{i\pi n}e^{-in\theta}=
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n]e^{-in(\theta-\pi)}=X(\theta-\pi)$$

The spectrum is just shifted by \$\pi\$. This is basically a consequence of the modulation property.

Comment: Sorry (: For some reason I thought the restriction of at least 15 reputation points is needed to click on the check mark too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt, according to The Photon's advice:

\$F_{DTFT} \{ (-1)^n \} = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^ne^{-i\theta n}\$

\$= \sum\limits_{even \space n's}e^{-i\theta n} - \sum\limits_{odd\space n's}e^{-i\theta n}\$

\$= \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\theta 2k} - \sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\theta (2m+1)}\$

\$= \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\theta 2k} - e^{-i\theta}\sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\theta 2m}\$

Looking at the sum \$\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\theta 2k}\$:

\$\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\theta 2k}=\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{0}e^{-i\theta 2k}+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{-i\theta 2k}-1\$

\$=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{i\theta 2k}+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{-i\theta 2k}-1\$

\$=\frac{1}{1-e^{-i 2\theta }}+\frac{1}{1-e^{i 2\theta }}-1\$

Then:

\$F_{DTFT} \{ (-1)^n \} = ... = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\theta 2k} - e^{-i\theta}\sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\theta 2m}\$

\$F_{DTFT} \{ (-1)^n \} = ... = (\frac{1}{1-e^{-i 2\theta }}+\frac{1}{1-e^{i 2\theta }}-1) - e^{-i\theta}(\frac{1}{1-e^{-i 2\theta }}+\frac{1}{1-e^{i 2\theta }}-1)\$

And then I somehow convolve this result with \$X(\theta)\$?